# How to view non-persistent faces of Azure Face Service?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am currently using Microsoft Azure Face API. I have a picture and "detect" method can detect a face in my picture. However, "identify" method can't identify that face. That person's pictures have been trained already. So, I want to see all detected faces (or non-persistent faces) to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have trained your person group already , pls call [this API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395247) to check its training status.

If the status value is "success" , could you pls share the details of your issue ? As I have gone through all of [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage) and seems everything works for me :

[image]

Comment: I trained already and everything is working except for some detected faces that couldn't be identified. And of course those detected faces belong to a person who was trained previously. That's why I want to view all temporary stored detected faces to see what the problem is. The problem might be because of not a good quality image or invalid detected faces, etc.

Comment: Hi @LongTruong I see, but based on this defect api reference : https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236 :No image will be stored. Only the extracted face feature(s) will be stored on server. The faceId is an identifier of the face feature and will be used in Face - Identify, Face - Verify, and Face - Find Similar. The stored face features will expire and be deleted 24 hours after the original detection call.

So I am afraid there is no way to fetch back face images by face id from face API .

Comment: As for current scenario, If you want to view all non-persistent faces detected by Detect API, I would suggest that you store the input Face images into Azure Blob Storage and rename it by face id your get from detect API by yourself . Then you can check each input Face image when you need. This is the only solution what I can find now.

Comment: Btw, in this doc : https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236 , there are some specific specifications for images that used for detecting , which will be helpful for your too .

Comment: Thank @Stanley Gong for your answer. It really helps.

Comment: Welcome ! have a nice day !